# Is there a method for shortening nested If...Then...Else statements?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create custom Excel functions to reduce menial mental tasks in my department.

The function works but freezes up 32-bit Excel for over a minute. For reference, the average workload is >10,000 rows of inputs.

```
Function Function_Name(Input)
If Val(Input) = 0 Then
    Function_Name = Input
    ElseIf Val(Input) = 1 Then Function_Name = Input
    ElseIf Val(Input) >= 1110 And Val(Input) <= 1999 Then Function_Name = "1110"
ElseIf Val(Input) >= 3100 And Val(Input) <= 3199 Then Function_Name = "3100"
'Similar ElseIf statements go on for 40+ lines......'
ElseIf Val(Input) >= 5700 And Val(Input) <= 5799 Then Function_Name = "5710"
'Note that they do not always return the lower limit of Val(Input), but sometimes may'
End If
End Function
```

The function provides accurate outputs, however takes long to process. I would like to know if there is a way to improve the back-end logic to reduce risk of Excel crashes and streamline processing.

Comment: the issue of time is not the IF/ELSEIF/ELSE function it is the fact that you are iterating >10,000 rows.  Load the values in bulk into a variant array and iterate the array.  Nothing you do to this function will speed up the code.

Comment: If you have cut-points, you can use binary search to find which interval something lies in, but if Excel is freezing, that is unlikely to be the main problem. For a concrete case, the binary search can be hard-wired by nested conditionals which implement a [binary decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram)

Comment: @JvdV undeclared integers are automatically wrapped in a `Variant`, [that's 16 bytes for any numeric value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)

Comment: @matthieuguindon, deleted my comment just as you replied as I was not sure if it would matter in this case anyway. But declaring a variable always makes sense. Byte-wise

Comment: Also readability-wise, performance-wise, maintanability-wise, and code-quality -wise... IOW declaring variables is always ...wise ;-)

Comment: So: `Function Function_Name(Input) as Long`. Should speed up the code a little bit. I recon `VAL` is used to return numeric value from a alphanumeric string, where data type string would not have a major impact, if any. @mathieuguindon

Comment: Also `ByVal input As Range`, assuming the input is some cell reference. Or `ByVal input As Long` if it's just any number.

Comment: @JvdV Thank you for your suggestion, I will attempt that. Your recollection of VAL() is spot on. My source data has leading zeroes so numeric values have to be stored as text, but VAL() converts them back to integers for the purpose of <= / >= comparison.

Comment: @JvdV I am afraid declaring the function ```As Long``` produced invalid results - my text outputs were turned into ```#VALUE``` errors in Excel and my numbers as text outputs were converted into Number format, which was not my intention.

Comment: Any reason to ouput numeric values as text?

Comment: Try invoking the function from the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) instead of from a worksheet cell. `#VALUE!` indicates a run-time error - the calc engine is swallowing it; the immediate pane won't.

Comment: Also, do not conflate numeric values with number formatting - if this function means to output anything that is or could be later used for any kind of math, you want numbers, not strings that look like they're numbers. Lastly, consider using an explicit conversion function like `CLng` instead of `Val`, lest you'll possibly run into problems when regional settings and different workstations using different decimal separators factor in.

Comment: In any case, it looks very much like the entire function could be scrapped and replaced with a VLOOKUP over a sorted lookup table; have the thresholds in column 1 and the output in column 2, sort ascending by col.1, and specify `TRUE` for the last argument of VLOOKUP.

Comment: @JvdV The output will contain leading zeroes. The output data is also intended for users who do not have time to manually reformat the output to include leading zeroes. It would also be time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Scrap the whole function, add a new sheet (hide it if you must), type "Threshold" in A1, "Value" in A2, then begin populating your lookup table (Ctrl+T) to make it an actual *table*, then name it, e.g. `refTable`):

```
Threshold   Value
        0   =NA()
     1100   1100
     1200   1200
     1300   1300
      ...   ...
```

Now wherever you were using that function (where B2 is your current "input"):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(refTable[[Threshold]:[Value]], B2, TRUE), B2)
```

The TRUE final argument makes the function match the largest value in column 1 that isn't greater than the lookup value, so 4256 would match the 4200 threshold, stopping short of 4300.

This assumes the lookup values aren't calculatable with simple math (i.e. that the 5710 result isn't a typo). Otherwise, there's an easy an much better-performing alternative:

```
=IF(B2>=1100,INT(B2/100)*100,B2)
```

If the input is greater than or equal to 1100, take the integer value of this input divided by 100, multiply that by 100 (there's probably a way to use a rounding function for that as well); otherwise just return the input. That should calculate pretty much instantly.

Comment: Mathieu, thank you so much for an alternative solution. A table is what I originally used as a reference for the rules and it already includes "threshold", which I had named "lower_limit", "upper_limit", and "result". if my understanding is correct, I can substitute the column names in the VLOOKUP formula you've provided to my own column names. In any case, I will attempt this solution and let you know if it works. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Marat_Muginov you only need the lower limit though - the most important part is the ascending sort, and the `TRUE` final argument to VLOOKUP.